# list reshape as similar to dictionary type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm dealing with patent data with pandas and numpy. 
the steps that I've done and data I've got from the raw data is below.

code

```
title = df['title'].tolist()
cpc = df_cpu['cpc'].tolist() 
z = zip(title, cpc)
```

result

```
 ('(real-time information transmission system)',
  'A61B-0005/0002, A61B-0005/0001, A61B-0005/0021'),
 ('(skincare counselling system)',
  'G06Q-0050/0010'),
 ('(apparatus for monitoring posture)',
  'A61B-0005/1116, A61B-0005/0002'),,....
)
```

It's a basically list(or tuple) with 'titles of patent' and it's own 'cpc codes' defining where sub technology the patents belongs to .
In this case, I'd like to split(or should I say reshape) the data I've got as I wrote below.
I guess it is not just split the data but reshape with specific rules.

```
('(real-time information transmission system)',
  'A61B-0005/0002'),
 '(real-time information transmission system)',
  'A61B-0005/0001')
 '(real-time information transmission system)',
  'A61B-0005/0021')
 ('(skincare counselling system)',
  'G06Q-0050/0010'),
 ('(apparatus for monitoring posture)',
  'A61B-0005/1116')
 ('(apparatus for monitoring posture)',
  'A61B-0005/0002'),,....
)
```

I thought about counting each commas and copy titles by the number of commas but I guess there should be more easy way to do it and I don't even know how to do with the way I thought.

Comment: u mind sharing the original data and see if there is a better way

Comment: It is just a Dataframe achieved from a **csv file**


`
title,  cpc code,

real-time information transmission system', 61B-0005/0002, A61B-0005/0001, A61B-0005/0021,

skincare counselling system, G06Q-0050/0010,

apparatus for monitoring posture, A61B-0005/1116, A61B-0005/0002

`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the end goal correctly, you want to use `split()` to split the cpc codes string, using `','` as the separator. This will generate a list, which you can then iterate through to create a new list/tuple.

Here is a snippet that I think accomplishes what you want:

```
from pprint import pprint

z = (('(real-time information transmission system)', 'A61B-0005/0002, A61B-0005/0001, A61B-0005/0021'),
     ('(skincare counselling system)', 'G06Q-0050/0010'),
     ('(apparatus for monitoring posture)', 'A61B-0005/1116, A61B-0005/0002'))

new_z = []
for title, cpc_codes_str in z:
     cpc_codes = cpc_codes_str.split(',')
     for code in cpc_codes:
          new_z.append((title, code))

pprint(tuple(new_z))
```

and this is what is printed:

```py
(('(real-time information transmission system)', 'A61B-0005/0002'),
 ('(real-time information transmission system)', ' A61B-0005/0001'),
 ('(real-time information transmission system)', ' A61B-0005/0021'),
 ('(skincare counselling system)', 'G06Q-0050/0010'),
 ('(apparatus for monitoring posture)', 'A61B-0005/1116'),
 ('(apparatus for monitoring posture)', ' A61B-0005/0002'))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you in advance. Really helped.  One more question though... What 'title', 'cpc_codes_str', 'code' supposed to be? Obviously title and cpc_codes_str should be the index that classify the title and the cpc code but where does 'code' come from? I guess it would be stupid question but still It doesn't get the output you mentioned....

Comment: It was a total stupid question. solved. appreciated @sglvladi